# NOT IN converted to LEFT JOIN giving different result

Tags: sql, join, sybase

please help on below query

```
select * from processed_h where c_type not in (select  convert(int,n_index) from index_m where n_index <>'0') **-- 902 rows**


select * from processed_h where c_type not in (2001,2002,2003)  **-- 902 rows**


select  convert(int,n_index) from index_m where n_index <>'0'  **--- 2001,2002,2003**
```

I tried to convert the not in to LEFT JOIN as below but it is giving me 40,000 rows returned what I am doing wrong

```
select A.* from processed_h A LEFT JOIN index_m B on A.c_type <> convert(int,B.n_index) and B.n_index <>'0' --40,000 + rows
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please, specify the query language in tags and title.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SYABSE 15.7

Comment: I'll bet that the LEFT JOIN is generating some results with a NULL value, which are being excluded in the where clause, since NULL can't equal anything.

Comment: yes I am getting NULL , But can you please let me know why I am not getting the NULL values when i used it as (2001,2002,2003)

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` returns ALL rows from the "left-hand" table regardless of whether the condition matches or not, which is why you are getting the "extra" rows.

An `INNER JOIN` *might* give you the same number of rows, but if there are *multiple* matches in the "right-hand" table then you'll still get more rows than you expect.

If `NOT IN` gives you the expected results then I'd stick with that.  You probably aren;t going to see significant improvements with a join.  The only reason I would change to an `INNER JOIN` is if I needed columns from the joined table in my output.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I don't want to hardcode the value so thought of using LEFT JOIN. Well if that doesnt improve preformance I can use a subquery

Comment: If you have performance problems, the `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` *may* solve it (compared to `NOT IN` in some cases). [Please check the syntax in the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug195.htm).

Comment: so I am planning to use    [code] select A.* from processed_h where c_type not in (select  convert(int,n_index) from index_m where n_index <>'0')

Comment: @ArunKumar I think that's the simplest and most straightforward.  Is there a reason you don;t want to use that?

Comment: @ Stanley ,I am little hesitate to use subquery as it will degrade the performance

Comment: @ArunKumar Do you have evidence to support that or are you guessing?  Most SQL engines can optimize subqueries quite effectively.  A `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` seems to be the best option (and should give the best performance).  An index on `c_type` should also improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

For the equivalent of a `NOT IN` using a left join, you need to link the tables as though the results in the linked table should be `IN` the resultset, then select only those records where the outer joined table did not return a record - like so:

```
select A.* from processed_h A 
LEFT JOIN index_m B on A.c_type = convert(int,B.n_index) and B.n_index <>'0'
WHERE B.n_index IS NULL
```

However, you might get better performance using a `NOT EXISTS` query instead:

```
select A.* from processed_h A 
where not exists
(select 1 from index_m B where B.n_index <>'0' and A.c_type = convert(int,B.n_index) )
```

Comment: 'select A.* from processed_h A 
LEFT JOIN index_m B on A.c_type = convert(int,B.n_index) and B.n_index <>'0'
WHERE B.n_index IS NULL'    Well the above query is giving more than 76 K result.. But the `not exists` works fine . I am going with `not exists`